# Unable to access UI dialog in Selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have a iframe, then a widget that contains the create invoice button. It is not inside the iframe but outside of it and I cannot access it.I cannot access this dialog using selenium webdriver java, Im trying to access the create invoice button using java:

```
</div><div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" id="saveBtnDialog" class="btn btn--primary">Create Invoice</button><button type="button" id="CancelBtnDialog" class="btn btn--primary">Cancel</button></div></div></div>
```

my code:

```
 private final By createInvoiceBtn = By.id("saveBtnDialog");
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-dialog-buttonset")));
 driver.findelement(createInvoiceBtn).click();
```

Comment: Could you share your java code? Which have you done.

Comment: I add it at the top any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my understanding if your `button` is not inside a `frame` and you are already in the `frame`

You need to switch from `frame` to `defaultContent` and then go to find `element` and perform action as below :-

```
//first switch to out side the frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//now implement WebDriverWait to provide wait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);

//wait until ExpectedConditions is not true
WebElement buttonEl = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("saveBtnDialog")));

//now you go for the action
buttonEl.click();
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: :( no luck org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: saveBtnDialog

Comment: @gabe Are you sure..this button is not inside a frame??

Comment: </iframe>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button id="saveBtnDialog" class="btn btn--primary" type="button">Create Invoice</button>
<button id="CancelBtnDialog" class="btn btn--primary" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>

Comment: see? its outside of the iframe the buttons are on the form but outside of the iframe i've never seen anything like it.

Comment: @gabe just execute this line to browser console and let me know what are you getting.... `document.getElementById('saveBtnDialog');`

Comment: document.getElementById('saveBtnDialog');
<button id="saveBtnDialog" class="btn btn--primary" type="button">

Comment: If you are getting that button by id on console where you want to click..that means there is no problem on above code..

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: saveBtnDialog
:(

Comment: @gabe Just one thing more...is this button visible on the page or after clicking some where it's getting visible??

Comment: To cheking visibility of element change `elementToBeClickable` to `visibilityOfElementLocated`...and let me know what happen??

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: saveBtnDialog

Comment: my code:driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  

//now implement WebDriverWait to provide wait
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);

//wait until ExpectedConditions is not true
  WebElement buttonEl = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("saveBtnDialog")));

//now you go for the action
  buttonEl.click();

Comment: Maybe i can try a Robot click

Comment: You can use `JavaScriptExecutor` here..may be it will help

Comment: `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('saveBtnDialog').click()");`...like that

Comment: i was just trying that so it executes and the test passes but the button is still not click. Nothing happens

Comment: @gabe Could you pls share me website url where you are doing test??

Comment: i got it.. I tab to the button then i enter  driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);